# how to put text after a line beginning with http?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have posts with links and I want to put HELP after all URLs starting with `http://`. So, posts with

```
http://google.net
http://yahoo.com
```

will be replaced by

```
http://google.net/HELP
http://yahoo.com/HELP
```

Comment: What programming language do you want to use? Java, Python, ...
Also, this is not a regex related question imho

Comment: @ncw based on the notepad++ tag I'd assume OP is wanting to use the program's *find and replace* feature, which accepts regular expressions.

Comment: You're right, I guess.

Comment: i want to use regex to do this

Answer (score 1):

In **Notepad++** to replace, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to open the *Replace* menu.

Find: `^http://.*$`
Replace by: `$0/HELP`

Comment: this doesnt work, it doesnt put HELP after end of every line begining with http. please test it yourself